# Prevent Android Boxed TextInputLayout scroll to bottom suddenly on cursor positioning

Tags: android, android-edittext, material-components-android, android-textinputlayout

I hava a long `TextInputEditText` in a `TextInputLayout` in a `ScrollView`, When I click at the start of the text to set the cursor position on the first line, but suddenly screen scrolls to bottom. see GIF below:

[image: bug: scroll suddenly]

Now if I remove Material box style from `TextInputLayout`, everything is ok. No sudden scroll on first line click.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/tilDescription"
            <!--style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"-->
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:hint="Product Description"
            app:counterEnabled="true"
```

see this GIF, when I remove style attribute:

[image: no sudden scroll here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/55nZa.gif]

What's wrong with outlined Box style?
**Caution**: I don't want to change `windowSoftInputMode` in AndroidManifest to `adjustPan`, I should use `adjustResize` because I have some other stuff which keyboard shouldn't appear on top of them.

Answer (score 1):

For multi-line `TextInputEditText`s that might be taller than the screen (especially after the soft keyboard is shown), you need to add the following to your `TextInputEditText`

```
app:textInputLayoutFocusedRectEnabled="false"
```

as described here: [Android TextInputLayout writing focus issue when height is bigger than the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62715709/android-textinputlayout-writing-focus-issue-when-height-is-bigger-than-the-scree)